# count the values based on condition in log

Tags: linux, shell

I have a log like below

```
11 13/06/2015:00:02:37
 10 13/06/2015:00:02:38
  7 13/06/2015:00:02:39
 10 13/06/2015:00:02:40
  1 13/06/2015:00:02:42
  1 13/06/2015:00:02:50
  1 13/06/2015:00:02:54
  2 13/06/2015:23:41:46
  1 13/06/2015:23:41:47
  2 13/06/2015:23:41:48
  1 13/06/2015:23:41:49
  2 13/06/2015:23:41:50
  1 13/06/2015:23:41:51
  2 13/06/2015:23:41:52
  1 13/06/2015:23:41:53
  2 13/06/2015:23:41:54
  1 13/06/2015:23:41:55
  1 13/06/2015:23:59:50
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:51
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:52
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:53
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:54
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:55
  1 13/06/2015:23:59:56
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:57
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:58
  2 13/06/2015:23:59:59
```

I want to count(1st field) the values based on minutes as in the above the we are seeing the count in secs ex: 2 counts  @ 13/06/2015:23:59:53 time. I want to sum them to show for minute wise . please help me how to code in shell/linux.

Thanks,

Comment: This sounds really complicated when done in a shell script.

Comment: But it sounds manageable if you, for example, use python to do it. Since this is a proper programming task, you should consider using a proper programming tool -- on nearly every machine out there, there's at least one usable scripting language installed, and on most, you can rely on perl, python, and possibly other languages being available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
cat path_to_your_log_file|awk '{split($2,res,":");var=res[1]":"res[2]":"res[3];counter[var]+=$1}END{for(i in counter){print counter[i],i}}'
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: @Dropout, Ignore the last field `second` which can split by ":" and use `dd/mm/yyyy:hh:mm` as key to count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach, using shell script and a bit of sed:

```
t=
sum=
f=$(mktemp)
sed -r 's/^ *(.*):[0-9]{2}$/\1/' txt > $f
while read line; do
  c=$(echo "$line"|cut -d' ' -f1)
  currt=$(echo "$line"|cut -d' ' -f2-)
  if [ -n "$t" ] && [ "$t" != "$currt" ]; then
    echo "$sum $t"
    t=$currt
    sum=$c
  elif [ -z "$t" ]; then
    t=$currt
    sum=$c
  else
    sum=$(($sum+$c))
  fi
done < $f
rm -f $f
if [ -n "$t" ] && [ "$t" = "$currt" ]; then
  echo "$sum $t"
fi
```